# cannot mount NFS share on my Mac PC to minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, mount, nfs

**Problem**

To make k8s multinodes dev env, I was trying to use NFS persistent volume in minikube with multi-nodes and cannot run pods properly. It seems there's something wrong with NFS setting. So I run `minikube ssh` and tried to mount the nfs volume manually first by `mount` command but it doesnt work, which bring me here.

When I run

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.xx.xx(=macpc's IP):/PATH/TO/EXPORTED/DIR/ON/MACPC /PATH/TO/MOUNT/POINT/IN/MINIKUBE/NODE
```

in minikube master node, the output is

```
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Some relavant info is

NFS client: minikube nodes

NFS server: my Mac PC

minikube driver: docker

Cluster comprises 3 nodes. (1 master and 2 worker nodes)

Currently there's no k8s resources (such as deployment, pv and pvc) in cluster.

minikube nodes' os is Ubuntu so I guess "nfs-utils" is not relavant and not installed. "nfs-common" is preinstalled in minikube.

Please see the following sections for more detail.

**Goal**

The goal is `mount` cmd in minikube nodes succeeds and nfs share on my Mac pc mounts properly.

**What I've done so far** is

**On NFS server side,**

created /etc/exports file on mac pc. The content is like

```
/PATH/TO/EXPORTED/DIR/ON/MACPC　-mapall=user:group 192.168.xx.xx(=the output of "minikube ip")
```

and run `nfsd update` and then `showmount -e` cmd outputs

```
Exports list on localhost:
/PATH/TO/EXPORTED/DIR/ON/MACPC 192.168.xx.xx(=the output of "minikube ip")
```

`rpcinfo -p` shows rpcbind(=portmapper in linux), status, nlockmgr, rquotad, nfs, mountd are all up in tcp and udp

`ping 192.168.xx.xx(=the output of "minikube ip")` says

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
and continues
```

It seems I can't reach minikube from host.

**On NFS client side,**

started nfs-common and rpcbind services with `systemctl` cmd in all minikube nodes. By running `sudo systemctl status rpcbind` and `sudo systemctl status nfs-common`, I confirmed rpcbind and nfs-common are running.

`minikube ssh` output

```
Last login: Mon Mar 28 09:18:38 2022 from 192.168.xx.xx(=I guess my macpc's IP seen from minikube cluster)
```

so I run

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.xx.xx(=macpc's IP):/PATH/TO/EXPORTED/DIR/ON/MACPC /PATH/TO/MOUNT/POINT/IN/MINIKUBE/NODE
```

in minikube master node.
The output is

```
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

`rpcinfo -p` shows only portmapper and status are running. I am not sure this is ok.

`ping 192.168.xx.xx(=macpc's IP)` works properly.

`ping host.minikube.internal` works properly.

`nc -vz 192.168.xx.xx(=macpc's IP) 2049` outputs `connection refused`

`nc -vz host.minikube.internal 2049` outputs `succeeded!`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does NFS work from another client with the matching DNS version?  (Other than the minikube VM/container)

Comment: @Rico Thanks for your comment! Do you mean using VM such as virtualbox as nfs client? If so, I have't tried that yet. In fact, I haven't used VM on PC for a long time. Is there an alternative to VM to check this out?

Comment: @Rico I will use docker container as a nfs client and see how it goes.

Comment: @Rico I successfully mounted nfs share dir on my host machine to another dir on the same machine. So it seems nfs server works just fine. And I did further digging and found out minikube with docker driver does not support nfs on multinode cluster (but I'm not pretty sure about this). It seems minikube with VM driver( or maybe hyperkit driver only?) can do this. I don't want to make minikube slower so I decided to switch to kind. But anyway, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to use another type of volume instead.